# Using Visual Basic to Select a Google Search Result in Internet Explorer

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, vba

I have VB code that goes to Google, fills in the search bar, and hits the search button.  Is there a way to have my program select a particular result after my search?  ie. I search for "cheese", I would like for my program to select the 2nd to last result (in this case, it is wwww.chuckecheese.com)

Comment: Do you mean extracting the links of all the results?

Comment: We can't know what you are talking about without the code.

Comment: @DougGlancy: This is a followup of the last question I guess :)

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I meant to actually click on the link so that the linked site loads (in this case, www.chuckecheese.com)

Comment: Isn't it the same thing? Extract all links. Identify the 2nd last link and then navigate to that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extract all links".  I would like to identify a specific link and then navigate to the site it links to

Comment: One way would be to scrape the page (using MSXML), then assign the response to a HTML DOMDocument, setting an object variable to all the "a" tags in the document. Then loop through them to figure out which one you want.

Comment: Hi JP, can you give more details on how to do this?  I am not too familiar with HSXML or DOMDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Sendkeys to emulate the tab and down arrow keys on the keyboard.  You can then navigate to your desired search results using these 2 keys

Answer (score 0):

Or you can bypass using an API and avoid ads or cost using **speech recognition** to improve your **Dictation** searches. Programming isn't programming if you aren't thinking outside the box and innovating your own solutions.
Coding comes with creativity and you won't know what that is if you don't try. This site is excellent for this very purpose and many have contributed to innovation in coding.
You will have to add a text file to your project and call it whatever you want, then change the path below in the code to your own path. The text file stays blank. The program will write your spoken search to file and then execute the search, constantly over-writing itself.
For some odd reason, this method greatly improves the fusion of speech recognition and dictation. You can speak an entire phrase and it will conduct the search. A good mic is a must and speaking clearly without background disturbances.

```
Imports System.Speech.Recognition

'Declarations:
Private ReadOnly Drone As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()

Private ReadOnly Qa As New DictationGrammar()

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object,
                           e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      
       'Dictation Mode | Google Engine
        Drone.LoadGrammarAsync(Qa)
        Drone.RequestRecognizerUpdate()
        Drone.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
        Drone.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5)
        Drone.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)
        Drone.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2)
        Drone.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)
        AddHandler Drone.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf Drone_SpeechRecognized
        Drone.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)

    End Sub

 Private Sub Drone_SpeechRecognized(sender As Object, e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
        Dim google As String = e.Result.Text.ToString

        Select Case (google)
            Case google

                If google <> "+" Then
                    'This section will take spoken word, write to file then execute search.
                    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
                    'Be sure to change the text file path below to your path if you are new to this program.
                    sb.AppendLine(google)
                    'Add your own path below here. you can also change google to youtube and conduct youtube searches
File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\justin.ross\source\repos\ScarlettCenturium\Scarlett Centurium\Scarlett Centurium\File.txt", sb.ToString())
                    google = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Uri.EscapeUriString(google)
                    Dim proc As New Process()
                    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(google)
                    proc.StartInfo = startInfo
                    proc.Start()
                    'This sendkey will close out previous tab on new search
                    SendKeys.Send($"^{{w}}")
                    Return
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

well you can use google api for that

goto http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/

download GoogleSearchAPI_0.4_alpha.zip

extract it and add reference to the dll file in your project ( in folder .net 2)

and you can use it like this

first import the library

```
Imports Google.API.Search
```

then in a sub or function put your code as

```
    Dim rf As String = "http://www.google.com"
    Dim v As New Google.API.Search.GwebSearchClient(rf)
    Dim result = v.Search(TextBox1.Text, 40)
    ' number (40) is the amount of fetched results ( change it if you want )
     For Each item In result

        If item.Url.Contains("chuckecheese") Then
            '  your code goes here
        End If



    Next
```